# How to change the font size / background of views after setAdapter has called in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a RecyclerView after the list has been populated by using **setAdapter** I want to change the font size and background of the child layouts,

> Blockquote Actually I have a button which I want to change day/night mode, based on that  I want to change the background color of the RecyclerView's TextView.

Is there any way to achieve this without calling the **setAdapter** again.

Comment: Yes , there is a way. Post your codes we can help

Comment: You should call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: That button is in Recyclerview?

Comment: @Shruti outside Recyclerview

Comment: Why don't you post your code

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it after calling

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is not all, you should do some work in "onBindViewHolder" method of your adapter. Keep under your adapter code a static variable with your current textsize:

public static int CurrentSize = 22;

CurrentSize will change the textsize of yours textview when onBindViewHolder is called, what to do is to change the textsize **before** the notifyDataSetChanged